# React Native Android - using local gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

i cant download **Gradle** when i use the command " **react-native run-android**" i counter this error:

> "Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for
>   details. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device
>   connected and have set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html "

i want to use the local Gradle that i have downloaded manually 
what should i do ?

Comment: Post the full error stack.

Comment: For running react native app you will start emulator or run on device.

Comment: The app won't build without gradle even if the emulator starts.